# recovering lost data after installing ubuntu on windows 10 using testdisk

Tags: data-recovery, testdisk

I have installed ubuntu over my windows 10 by mistake.I already had a ubuntu partition so i tried to reinstalled ubuntu but actually i installed it on windows partition and all my partitions are lost.I had my important data on windows partitions.So please help me out to recover that data.I tried testdisk from live usb but it only displays files on ubuntu.
I have not used my installed ubuntu so the files are not overwritten.So please provide me ways to recover data.

Now , i have tried recovering using testdisk.In quick search  i am unable to find the lost partitions and in deeper search the search space system uses is 1700 gb while my actual hdd size is 500 gb which is displayed correctly at the start and after the deep search it asks me to check bios setting and jumper settings.Please help me out ...

Comment: Do you have both Windows and Ubuntu boot? Do you have Windows boot in your Ubuntu's grub boot menu?

Comment: No on startup system directly boots in ubuntu

Comment: STOP using system, boot from live installer. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery  and: https://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu

Comment: I agree with oldfred.  Also, TestDisk has a Step-by-Step to follow that is pretty informative for recovering partitions:  http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step

Comment: how to get qphotorec??
i tried installing it but it was beta version so id didnt open

Comment: If u cant access ur 500gb drive from ubuntu drive menu from file manger then it cant be accessed.(if it shows ntfs error then it can be accessed)..u might have overwritten your ubuntu over windows,because of wrong installation

Comment: Testdisk won't be of any use since you overwrote parts of the metadata. Use more appropriate tools (like RecuperaBit, see next comment).

Comment: For reference, the same question has been posted here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/311250/84179 (in case someone wants to look at possible answers there as well)